# How can I filter for "happening either now or in the future"?

Tags: views

I want to have an exposed filter for noticeboard items that chooses between "current & upcoming" and "past".

I'm using the [composite views filter](https://drupal.org/project/composite_views_filter) module to allow different filtering based on what is selected.

"Past" is easy - anything where the start date is before "today".

"Current & upcoming" is tricky.

"Current" by itself would be anything where the start date is before or equal to "today", and the end date is after or equal to "today".

"Upcoming" by itself would be anything where the start date is greater than or equal to "today".

I can't figure out a way to merge the two without having to duplicate all the other filters.

Comment: Are you filtering on date field or content (node) created value ?

Comment: This is a date field.